# Run erlang script from Linux crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron, erlang, erlang-shell

I have a erlang script (Ex. test), I can run it from command line using ./test but I want to run the script from crontab of the Linux server. As I am new in using erlang script, can someone guide me how to run it from crontab?
want to run the script everyday once at 12.30AM.

Comment: What did you try? What does your current `crontab -l` show?

Comment: currently there is no erlang script in the cron. In cron there are .sh scripts only now. Need to know the procedures of adding any erlang script in cron

Comment: `crontab -e` would be my suggestion. When the editor pops up, copy a line and edit the time spec and program to run, save and exit. Done.

Comment: Adding to the comment by TedLyngmo : This would use `vi` as editor. If you want to use a different one, use i.e. `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`.

Comment: @Raichen, edit your question to show how you invoke it from the command line

Comment: did you try `escript` command?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.